# Parse JSON response

Tags: json, response, string.format

I create a record in one system and that creates the similar record in another and returns the corresponding ID from the destination system which I would to stamp in my source.
Deserialized the response to a map of string,string :

```
Map<String,String> mapresp = (Map<String,String>)JSON.deserialize(resp.getbody(),Map<String, string>.class);
```

and below is the result

> {Account:{"attributes":{"type":"Account","url":"/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/Account/0014T000005aLUrQAM"},"FieldId__c":"0010I00002Kyu2zQAB","Id":"0014T000005aLUrQAM"}}

How do I get to the value of FieldId__c?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'd be able to do that with deserializing to a `Map<String, String>` like you currently are.

You could use `JSON.deserializeUntyped()` and work with a `Map<String, Object>` to be able to dive deeper into your deserialized json, but since you're working with an `SObject` (even if it's from a different org), it'd be easier to just deserialize it as an `Account`.

```java
String myJson = '{"attributes":{"type":"Account","url":"/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/Account/0014T000005aLUrQAM"},"FieldId__c":"0010I00002Kyu2zQAB","Id":"0014T000005aLUrQAM"}}';

// The second argument to deserialize() tells it which object/class to expect
// It's going to be <SObject name, or Apex class name>.class
// The return type of deserialize() is always "Object", even though we told it what
//   class to use to do the deserialization.
// Because of that, we also need to explicitly type-cast the result
Account acct = (Account)JSON.deserialize(myJson, Account.class);
```

You'd then access your target value the same way that you'd access any other field on an SObject, `acct.FieldId__c`.

This does assume that your `Account` object has a `FieldId__c` field (that you have at least read access to) in the org that you're running this code in.

As long as you don't try to insert the deserialized account (the Id won't be valid in both the source and target orgs), and keep it strictly *in memory*, then things should work out fine.

Comment: Hi Derek,
The value in FieldId__c is the ID of the source org and the value that I receive in ID is the value from the destination org.So, would need to query for FieldId__c = Id in this org to fetch the record.
Modified the code per below, but I get an error that variable does not exist, which is obvious. But how do I get the value of FieldId__c?
Account acc= (Account)JSON.deserialize(myJson, account.class);
for(Account a : [select CustomId__c from account where Id=:acc.FieldId__c])
    
}

Comment: Also, my JSON response has the additional ID value prior to the attributes like -

{0014T000005aLUrQAM={"attributes":{"type":"Account","url":"/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/Account/0014T000005aLUrQAM"},"FieldId__c":"0010I00002Kyu2zQAB","Id":"0014T000005aLUrQAM"}}

So the string value doesn't really begin from "attributes". Is there a way to not include this "0014T000005aLUrQAM="?

Comment: @Priya When you system.debug() a Map, it gives you the output as `key=value`. If that were truly included in the response body, you wouldn't be able to deserialize using the JSON class (because `key=value` is not valid JSON). If you were to debug the response body, I think you'd find it **doesn't** contain `0014T000005aLUrQAM=` anywhere. Also, again, my solution assumes that you have `FieldId__c` defined on your target object (`Account`) in both orgs. You might want to edit your question to add more detail if my solution doesn't work for you.

Comment: Hi Derek, this is the response. I've added additional details to the question if(resp.getstatuscode()==200){
system.debug('Response:' + resp.getbody());
//debug --Response:{"0014T000005aTXUQA2":"{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Account\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/Account/0014T000005aTXUQA2\"},\"FieldId__c\":\"0010I00002KzuDxQAJ\",\"Id\":\"0014T000005aTXUQA2\"}"}//

Comment: Map<String,String> mapresp = (Map<String,String>)JSON.deserialize(resp.getbody(),Map<String, string>.class);
system.debug('Mapresp:' + mapresp);
//debug
{0014T000005aTXUQA2={"attributes":{"type":"Account","url":"/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/Account/0014T000005aTXUQA2"},"FieldId__c":"0010I00002KzuDxQAJ","Id":"0014T000005aTXUQA2"}}

Account acc = (Account)JSON.deserialize(??,Account.class);

Comment: ,thanks for your input. Finally I could get the value using this. Although, I still do not know how to parse my response to the string value as below -                                            String myJson = '{"Account":{"attributes":{"type":"Account","url":"/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/Account/0014T000005aRZAQA2"},"FieldId__c":"0010I00002KzV6mQAF","Id":"0014T000005aRZAQA2"}}';

Comment: Map<String,Object> mapresp1 = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeuntyped(myJson);
system.debug('mapresp is' +mapresp1);
Map<String,Object> newmap = (Map<String,Object>)mapresp1.get('Account');
system.debug('mapresp is' +newmap);
system.debug(newmap.get('FieldId__c'));